# Is it possible to select multiple columns in Virtual Treeview?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

I need to add functionality to copy a rectangular selection of nodes and columns, but I can't find any way to actually select multiple columns in a Virtual Treeview (beside toFullRowSelect).

Am I just missing something? And if not, is there a descendant out there with grid-like multicolumn select support?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So after some testing I came up with the following, thanks DiGi for the extra push. DrawSelection won't work with this solution so it needs to be disabled. Since I don't think I'll need to do this again soon I didn't write a descendant.

Set toDisableDrawSelection, toExtendedFocus and toMultiSelect to True.

Declare the following variables/properties somewhere suitable:

```
StartSelectedColumn: integer;
FirstSelectedColumn: integer;
LastSelectedColumn: integer;
Selecting: boolean;
```

Update the following events:

OnKeyDown

```
if (not Selecting) and (Key = VK_SHIFT) then
begin
  StartSelectedColumn := vtMain.FocusedColumn;
  FirstSelectedColumn := StartSelectedColumn;
  LastSelectedColumn := StartSelectedColumn;
  Selecting := true;
end;
```

OnKeyUp

```
if Key = VK_SHIFT then
  Selecting := false;
```

OnFocusChanged

```
if Selecting then
begin
  if column < StartSelectedColumn then
  begin
    FirstSelectedColumn := column;
    LastSelectedColumn := StartSelectedColumn;
  end
  else if column > StartSelectedColumn then
  begin
    FirstSelectedColumn := StartSelectedColumn;
    LastSelectedColumn := column
  end
  else
  begin
    FirstSelectedColumn := column;
    LastSelectedColumn := column;
  end;
end
else
begin
  StartSelectedColumn := column;
  FirstSelectedColumn := column;
  LastSelectedColumn := column;
end;
```

OnBeforeCellPaint

```
if vtMain.Selected[node] and InRange(column, FirstSelectedColumn, LastSelectedColumn) then
begin
  if vtMain.Focused then
    TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := vtMain.Colors.FocusedSelectionColor
  else
    TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := vtMain.Colors.UnfocusedSelectionColor;
  TargetCanvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
  TargetCanvas.FillRect(CellRect);
end;
```

OnPaintText

```
if vtMain.Selected[node] and InRange(column, FirstSelectedColumn, LastSelectedColumn) then
begin
  if vtMain.Focused then
    TargetCanvas.Font.Color := clHighlightText
  else
    TargetCanvas.Font.Color := vtMain.Font.Color;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try enable/add *toGridExtensions* in *TreeOptions.MiscOptions*. It enables free moving in columns by cursor keys, but VT still deselect column on leaving. But I'm sure that is possible to "fix" it by custom draw and remembering starting node and column.

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't work very well when you want to use a mouse. It does however "solve" the problem so upvote. :)

Answer (score 1):

One more tip - look at **OnStateChange** event, maybe you can use

```
procedure TSomeForm.VTreeStateChange(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Enter,Leave: TVirtualTreeStates);
begin
  if tsDrawSelecting in Enter then
  begin
    // Save position
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll look at it later. :) Thanks!