# How to make a selection over a large area of cells in virtualtreeview?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

I am using TVirtualTreeView as an excellent alternative to the old TStringgrid.

On one feature that I am missing though, is the possibility to make selections of an any area of cells (other than a single column, row or the whole area).

I can not find any solution to this, does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: You can set the selected[] property for each and every Node (row). In the Header can you set which columns are selected. Set Multiselect to true in the options.

Comment: I have tried, but I can not select multiple columns. There is no options in TVirtualTreeColumn.Option or in TVirtualTreeColumns.

Comment: There is no such feature in VT. But you can handle this by your own in your data structure (e.g. as a bit mask, where each bit will represent one column and state if it's selected or not). And this mask you can change in a certain column click event and draw it in a some cell draw event.

Comment: Thanks!
i have thought of the same solution too, but right now I havn't the  time on my current project. It would be interesting if anyone already has made the implementation in a component of their own.

What made me curious is the feature to mark an area with the mouse pressed down - There will be a blue (transparent) rectangle over the cells but for what reason?

If I take the time to implement a selection treeview I will put up the code for review..

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491198/is-it-possible-to-select-multiple-columns-in-virtual-treeview?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Canvas Draw For Show Own Selection Area of Cell.